# Featured Products linking to different url

Tags: opencart

I have assigned some featured products in my homepage and somehow the link to product is different from that of my menu.

For example:
From menu:
http://www.example.com/store/products/littleshirt

From featured products section:
http://www.example.com/store/littleshirt

I am using opencart extension menu but I don't supposed that is the source of this problem.
I need the URL to point to same location as the url for featured product link to the product nicely but the side product menu only display parent categories.

Is there anyway to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The "OpenCart Featured Products and News" Module is a jquery based open cart module which is shows the Selected Featured Products and/or News or relevant posts

OpenCart featured products and news is useful and has a nice plugin.

http://codecanyon.net/item/opencart-featured-products-and-news/4368564?ref=wpproducts

Answer (score 0):

Known problem for me. Using canonicals referencing the desired URL for these duplicates is sort of a solution for this problem. For example:

*http://www.example.com/store/littleshirt*
contains a canonical to the desired URL:
*http://www.example.com/store/products/littleshirt*

This will prefent search engines from indexing/crawling the duplicate page and your correct/desired page from losing metrics.

p.s. I had to change the URL's to example.com for my post to get through.